# Enumeration Null pointer Exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, http-headers, request, enumeration

Hi I am using the HttpServletRequest and trying to get the set of headers set.

Here is the code :

```
public static Map<String, String> getHeaders(HttpServletRequest request) { 
   Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

  Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames(); 
  if (headerNames != null) {
            while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
                String header = request.getHeader(headerName);
                headers.put(headerName, header);
            }
        }
        return headers;

}
```

This method seems to be throwing a Null pointer exception at the headerNames.nextElement().

Is it possible that the hasMoreElements check returns true but the element headerNames.nextElement in turn causes the null pointer exception?

Stack Trace :

```
    Stack trace : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.equalsIgnoreCase(ByteChunk.java:608) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.equalsIgnoreCase(MessageBytes.java:325) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.NamesEnumerator.findNext(MimeHeaders.java:414) at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.NamesEnumerator.nextElement(MimeHeaders.java:438) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.NamesEnumerator.nextElement(MimeHeaders.java:396) at generateRequestHeaderMap...
```

It would be great if you guys could help me out with this issue.

Comment: Post the stacktrace and indicate exactly which lines are referenced in the stacktrace.

Comment: Stack trace : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.equalsIgnoreCase(ByteChunk.java:608)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.equalsIgnoreCase(MessageBytes.java:325)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.NamesEnumerator.findNext(MimeHeaders.java:414)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.NamesEnumerator.nextElement(MimeHeaders.java:438)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.NamesEnumerator.nextElement(MimeHeaders.java:396)
      at generateRequestHeaderMap...

Comment: What version iof Tomcat?  Precisely.

Comment: Question: is that your real code; i.e. the actual code giving the exception?   Or has it been edited by you to "clarify" it?

Comment: These might be useful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is caused by a mangled request.  Here is what `findNext()` is doing (in Tomcat 6.0.18):

```
private void  findNext() {
    next=null;
    for(  ; pos< size; pos++ ) {
        next=headers.getName( pos ).toString();
        for( int j=0; j<pos ; j++ ) {
            if( headers.getName( j ).equalsIgnoreCase( next )) {
                // duplicate.
                next=null;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( next!=null ) {
            // it's not a duplicate
            break;
        }
    }
    // next time findNext is called it will try the
    // next element
    pos++;
}
```

The salient lines are this:

```
next=headers.getName( pos ).toString();

if( headers.getName( j ).equalsIgnoreCase( next )) {
```

If the header is mangled then it may be possible for `getName(j)` to return a `null`.  If that happens, then the `ByteChunk` path for the `equalsIgnoreCase` method will throw an NPE.

If you are going to track this down scientifically, you need to:

- get hold of the actual raw bytes of the request, and examine them forensically to determine the nature of the corruption (if any)
- set up a test harness to allow you to run your app on this request with a debugger attached .... and trap the exception at source.

The non-scientific approach would be to upgrade Tomcat to the most recent patch release of Tomcat 6 ... or a later version.  It might fix the problem.  Or not.

Here's another report of this problem in Tomcat 6.0.20 from back in 2010:

- https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201002.mbox/%3C4B7EBCE4.1010604@christopherschultz.net%3E

Answer (score 0):

This is how I successfully patched the Apache Tomcat in JBoss 6.1.0 Final (in deploy/jbossweb.sar/jbossweb.jar) based on Apache Tomcat 6.0.20 source code:

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.NamesEnumerator.findNext()

```
    private void findNext() {
        next=null;
        for(  ; pos< size; pos++ ) {
            // (4 lines changed): check mb for null as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493552/enumeration-null-pointer-exception/37493888#37493888
            MessageBytes mb = headers.getName( pos );
            if (mb != null) {
                next=mb.toString();
            }
            for( int j=0; j<pos ; j++ ) {
                // (2 lines changed): check mb and nex for null as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493552/enumeration-null-pointer-exception/37493888#37493888
                mb = headers.getName( j );
                if(mb != null && next != null && mb.equalsIgnoreCase( next )) {
                    // duplicate.
                    next=null;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // new (just 1 comment line): if mb == null we assume next == null, thus it will be a duplicate (i.e. not found, causing no break)
            if( next!=null ) {
                // it's not a duplicate
                break;
            }
        }
        // next time findNext is called it will try the
        // next element
        pos++;
    }
```

Sure it does not avoid the non-thread safe implementation mentioned in https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201002.mbox/%3c27699460.post@talk.nabble.com%3e but at least if avoids the NullPointerException during reading unnecessary headers.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's ugly but that's what I did:

```
public HashMap<String, String> fetchAllHeadersAsHashMap(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    Collection<String> headerNames = null;

    int retries = 0;
    int maxRetries = 5;
    
    //this is a bug in tomcat, which doesn't return the headers in case someone else is removing or adding a header
    while (headerNames == null) {
        if (retries >= maxRetries) {
            break;
        }
        try {
            if (retries > 0) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            headerNames = new ArrayList<>(httpServletResponse.getHeaderNames());
        } catch (Throwable th) {
        }
        retries = retries + 1;
    }

    if (org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.isEmpty(headerNames)) {
        return headers;
    }

    for (String headerName : headerNames) {
        Object value = null;
        try {
            value = httpServletResponse.getHeader(headerName);
        } catch (Throwable th) {

        }
        if (value == null) {
            continue;
        }

        headers.put(headerName, httpServletResponse.getHeader(headerName));
    }
    return headers;
}
```